# Opengl в Visual C++: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

```
#include<glglut.h>

void Draw()
{
}

void Initialize()
{
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("gg");
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    Initialize();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Выдаются ошибки

> `1>ррпо.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp____glutInitWithExit@12 в функции _glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK@8
> 1>ррпо.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8 в функции _glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK@4
> error LNK1120: 2 неразрешенных внешних элемента`

Все библиотеки для работы с OpenGL подключены.

Comment: У тебя слеш в неправильную сторону `gl/glut`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
```

Русифицированные сообщения об ошибках это абсолютное зло, их переводили [люди которые не знают как работает компилятор](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B8). Unresolved external symbol гуглите.

Можно еще так попробовать:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glut32.lib")
```

Comment: не в каком случае не работает, те же оибки остаются

Comment: Еще одна шаманская директива. Попробуйте, тяжело дебагать вслепую.

    #define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK

Comment: это помогло, только к превиликому удивлению ошибка запуск невозможен так как отсутствует glut32.dll 
я все делал по http://www.liveinternet.ru/users/oectacann/post153937570/

Comment: Ссылка на GLUT
http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html

Comment: Это неверно

    glut.h и glaux.h копировать в: :\\include\GL 

    (например у меня c:\Program Files\Microsoft    SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\gl\)

    *)glut.lib  glut32.lib glaux.lib копировать в:  :\\lib

Нужны папки:

    \Visual Studio 2012\VC\include
    \Visual Studio 2012\VC\lib

Правда тогда вы сможете собрать проект только у себя на компьютере.

[Смотрите этот тред][1]
[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/147227/







  [1]: http://

Comment: если не верно то почему там 20 комментариев спасибо все работает? кстате у меня тоже заработало, когда я в другом месте скачал glut32.dll и у windows/system32 скопировал(заменил тот что раньше копировал) и заработало

Comment: @LLIAKAJ
Хотя скорее всего мое последнее замечание и не особо важно, если вам чем-то помог мой ответ пометьте его как правильный. (Галочка слева от основного ответа)